# How to change period to 1 minute in Bloomberg API for R

Tags: r, bloomberg

EDIT:

updated the code but still have not been able to get intraday, 1 minute data.
I have the following code:

```
suppressMessages(library("Rblpapi"))
conn = blpConnect()

sec<-c("eurusd curncy", "eur2y curncy", "eur12m curncy")
flds<-"PX_LAST"
ovr = c("PERIOD" = "1")

a = as.data.frame(bdh(sec,flds,start.date=as.Date("2019-01-01 07:00"),end.date=as.Date("2019-01-31 07:00"), include.non.trading.days="FALSE", overrides = ovr))
```

Can't seem to get the period to change to 1 minute intervals.

Comment: Please specify the packages used

Comment: If you want 1 minute bar data, you need to call getBars, not bdh.See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56990427/829571